# Z-Index stacking?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm trying to make this gray bar tuck underneath the purple div in the background using z-index in CSS (then pull out with JavaScript when a button is clicked... but that works!).

This is what it looks like now:

[image: image of it now]

The HTML for the area looks like this:

```
<div id="body">
        <div id="container">

            <header>
                ... header content ...
            </header>


            <div id="pullBar">
                ... pullBar content ...
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And this is what the CSS for #pullbar and #body look like:

```
#pullBar{
    padding:7px 15px;
    height:108px;
    width:90%;
    background:#BCC6CC;
    margin-left:-90%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background:#401445;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index is nested because of the relative elements (which are nested as well). So you could either move the pullbar to the same level as #body:

```
<div id="body">
        <div id="container">

            <header>
                ... header content ...
            </header>
        </div>
</div>

<div id="pullBar">
    ... pullBar content ...
</div>
```

Or you could use absolute positioning on the pullbar to place it in a 'new' layer, so the z-index will be at the same level as #body too.

Have a look here as well: [z-index on absolutely positioned nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051857/z-index-on-absolutely-positioned-nested-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Tge reason is that the pullbar div inherits the same z-index as the body.Make the pullbar same level as body...

```
  <body>
  </body>

  <div id="pullbar">
  </div>
```

This code is ok. But it is not recommended to make the pullbar div as the same level as the body.
Use another div like.some main div in place of body and then make the pullbar div in level with the main div